# Call parent function from child component in React-Native ListView row

Tags: function, listview, react-native, row, components

I have seen a few examples of this question but was unable to get any to work, or completely understand how it all fits together. I have a component called `ParentListView` and another called `ChildCell` (a row within the listView) I want the `onPress` from the `ChildCell` to call a function in `ParentListView`.

```
class ChildCell extends Component {

  pressHandler() {
    this.props.onDonePress;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.pressHandler()} >
          <Text>Child Cell Button</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

}
```

and in `ParentListView`:

```
class ParentListView extends Component {  

//...

  render() {

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        style={styles.listView}
        renderRow={this.renderCell}
        renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
        />
    );
  }

  renderCell() {
    return (
      <ChildCell onDonePress={() => this.onDonePressList()} />
    )
  }

  onDonePressList() {
    console.log('Done pressed in list view')
  }

}
```

I think that is all the pertinent code. I can get the press to register wishing the `ChildCell`, but cannot get the method to fire in `ParentListView`. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 1:

in `ParentListView` if I change the props passed in to this:

```
<ChildCell onDonePress={this.onDonePressList.bind(this)} />
```

I get the `Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.onDonePressList')` error at compile time when rendering the cell.

If I put the console.log directly in like this:

```
<ChildCell onDonePress={() => console.log('Done pressed in list view')} />
```

it logs the message fine.

If I leave it like I had originally:

```
<ChildCell onDonePress={() => this.onDonePressList()} />
```

It crashes on buttonPress with the `Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating '_this2.onDonePressList')`

UPDATE 2:

OK, I have tried binding the method in the constructor like so:

```
class ParentListView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDonePressList = this.onDonePressList.bind(this);
    this.state = {...};
}
```

but it gives me this error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'this.onDonePressList')` and will not run.

UPDATE 3:
[Here is a link to a react native playground](https://rnplay.org/apps/riGTTw)

Comment: have you tried writing your components with a constructor function? as per the react docs: "We recommend that you bind your event handlers in the constructor so they are only bound once for every instance" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: I tried (see update 2) but to no avail. Does not `() => myFunction()` do the binding for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling `onDonePress` in `pressHandler` like this:

```
pressHandler() {
  this.props.onDonePress()
}
```

Also, bind `this` to your `renderRow` and `renderSectionHeader`:

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    style={styles.listView}
    renderRow={this.renderCell.bind(this)}
    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader.bind(this)}
    />
```

I've set up an example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/DcdAuw) using the above function.

https://rnplay.org/apps/DcdAuw

Comment: When called like that I get: `Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating '_this2.onDonePressList')`

Comment: Yours works fine lol. I have tried `<ChildCell onDonePress={() => console.log('Done pressed in list view')} />` and that works, but trying to get the parent to call its own function using `this` seems to be the trouble...

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between what you have and what I have set up, is there something I'm missing? I've updated both components to use classes now in the example, but the functionality is the same.

Comment: From what I can tell, you have still not added the `()` to the end of `this.props.onDonePress` ( should be `this.props.onDonePress()` )

Comment: Also, anyway you can recreate the issue on rnplay.org?

Comment: https://rnplay.org/apps/riGTTw is the fork I added to your replay.org project, and I get the error. I have changed it to a sectioned ListView as it is in my app.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you just need to bind the `renderRow` and         `renderSectionHeader` functions to the class. Check out this working example https://rnplay.org/apps/DcdAuw

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much. Coming from Objective-C, the implementation and use of `this` has been a real tricky concept to grasp.

Comment: Tell me about it, it has been confusing for me especially in cases like this!